# How to turn OFF "magic_quotes_gpc" on yahoo web hosting

Tags: php, .htaccess, joomla, web-hosting, yahoo

I have `Joomla` CMS website which is developed in `JOomla 3.0` version and when I goes to host it on Yahoo Web hosting. And when I try to access my control panel, it gives me Error that "Your host needs to disable `magic_quotes_gpc` to run this version of Joomla!" .
   So how can I turn OFF `magic_quotes_gpc` OFF on yahoo web hosting

Answer (score 0):

Try the following (stop when the issue is resolved):

- Add the following line to your `.htaccess` file:

  ```
  php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
  ```
- If the above doesn't work (or if your website crashes), remove the line that you have added and add the below line to your `.htaccess` file:

  ```
  php_value magic_quotes_gpc Off
  ```
- If the above doesn't work (or if your website crashes), remove the line that you have added and then create a file called `php.ini` and place it under the root directory of your Joomla website, and add the following line to it:

  ```
  magic_quotes_gpc = Off
  ```
- If the above doesn't work, then create a file called `.user.ini` (note that there is a dot before "user") and add the following line to it:

  ```
  magic_quotes_gpc = Off
  ```

Hope this helps!